# Android studio Handler not reading Bluetooth messages correctly

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, type-conversion, android-handler

I am sending data from an arduino through a Bluetooth module. I am simply streaming different integers;

```
int bluetoothData;

//give value to bluetoothData

Serial1.println(bluetoothData);
```

In my Android code, I have a Bluetooth socket that receives the data from the arduino. The data is taken care of by a Handler. And here lies the problem, sometimes the data is misread. For instance, I am sending '100', but instead the Handler saves in my database '000' or I send '194' and what is read is '994'. Sometimes such a reading mistake would occur once in every 15. Sometimes there will not be any mistake at all. Does someone know what may the reason be? Is it some hardware malfunction of the bluetooth module, is it the way I am reading the data, etc. Here is the Android code for the Thread receiving data:

```
final int RECIEVE_MESSAGE = 1;
...
mmInStream = socket.getOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[256];  // buffer store for the stream
int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

// Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
 while (true) {
 bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer); 
 h.obtainMessage(RECIEVE_MESSAGE, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
 }
```

Here is the code for the handler itself:

```
public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case RECIEVE_MESSAGE:                                                   
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);                 
                sb.append(strIncom);                                                
                int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");                            
                if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                            
                    String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);               
                    sb.delete(0, sb.length());
                    btData = Integer.parseInt(sbprint);
                    M = btData;
                    insert = mDataBaseHelper.insert(M,DataBaseHelper.TABLE_Temp);
                }
```

Comment: you are using the same buffer in every message: `h.obtainMessage(RECIEVE_MESSAGE, bytes, -1, buffer)`

Comment: Thank you so much, never considered that, it worked.

Comment: and to avoid creation of 1000s buffers you could use `android.support.v4.util.Pools.SynchronizedPool<T>` for example